# go to my route after authentication when I use middleware in laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, routes, middleware

I have this route in web.php (laravel 5.4)

```
Route::get('/sample', function (App\User $user) {
    return "inja sampleee";
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

I want  after when user enter  /sample path in browser Beginning  login user then  show massage "this  is  sampleee".  but by this code after authentication go to the way that define in handle methods  Middleware. how can return to what I want in my route that define in my route.

I changed App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php is it correct file?
I added return $next($request); after  //  return redirect('/home'); line.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
          //  return redirect('/home');
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[image: after login]

Comment: Add `return $next($request);` line on handle method of the middleware if successfully authenticated

Comment: @RavishaHesh I added your opiopn in handle method but in stay in login page after authenticated, it doeznot redirect to my route that set route

Comment: please add code of your middleware

Comment: @RavishaHesh I changed App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php is it correct file?

Comment: Don't change RedirectIfAuthenticated file, it has nothing to do with api auth, I thought you are using custom middleware, just leave it as it was. What the output you get when you call to route "/sample"?

Comment: @RavishaHesh I insert picture after login I left here my id can youe send me message and help me. masoudy.maryam@gmail.com